# Using two jQuery libraries in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a custom page in which the menu requires one jQuery library and the popup requires another. When I put the popup jQuery at the end of the code, only the popup function works and it stops my menu animation. If I do the reverse, the menu works and the popup button stops working. Why does this happen and how can I resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

```html
<!-- here this is the code without popup box -->
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <title>webmap</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Slide Down Box Menu with jQuery and CSS3" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, css3, box, sliding, menu, cube, navigation, portfolio, thumbnails" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jsuntitled/css/ol.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sideicon_file/css/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sideicon_file/css/component.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sideicon_file/css/style1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="sideicon_file/css/animated_button.css">
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Material Design for Bootstrap -->


        <link href="popup/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Font Awesome -->

        <!-- jQuery -->


    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <script src="popup/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="popup/src/jquery-prompt21.js"></script>
    <script src="popup/js/handlers.js"></script>



    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="sideicon_file/js/ease.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sideicon_file/js/segment.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body
        {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }


        #map
        {
            height: 500px;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        span.reference
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 600px;
            bottom: 10px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

            span.reference a
            {
                color: #aaa;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
                margin-right: 30px;
            }

                span.reference a:hover
                {
                    color: #ddd;
                }

        ul.sdt_menu
        {
            margin-top: 0px;
        }


        div#banner
        {
            width: 1350px;
            height: 40px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            border: #639 1px solid;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            div#banner > #banner_backdrop
            {
                position: relative;
                height: 40px;
            }

            div#banner > #banner_content
            {
                position: relative;
                width: 96%;
                height: 40px;
                margin-top:10px;
                top: -40px;
                color: #0099CC;
                font-size: 20px;
                left: 100px;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            div#banner > #img1
            {
                position: absolute;
                background: url(images/isrologo.png) no-repeat;
                width: 80px;
                height: 70px;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
            }

            div#banner > #img2
            {
                position: absolute;
                background: url(images/title.png) no-repeat;
                width: 80px;
                height: 70px;
                top: 0px;
                left: 1280px;
            }

        .ol-mouse-position
        {
            top: auto;
            bottom: 2em;
        }

        .ol-overviewmap
        {
            bottom: 2em;
        }

        .ol-zoomslider
        {
            top: 10em;
        }

        .ol-rotate
        {
            top: 2.5em;
        }

        .draw-point
        {
            right: 3em;
            top: .5em;
        }

        #wrapper
        {
        position:relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 80px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: #009999;

        }
        .col-lg-6{
        width: 100px;
        margin-left:200px;          
                    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="banner">
        <div id="banner_backdrop"></div>
        <div id="img1"></div>
        <div id="img2"></div>
        <div id="banner_content">
            Geo Spatial Information
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div>
            <ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">

                <li >
                    <a href="#"  >
                        <img src="images/landuse.jpg" alt="" />
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link"><input type="checkbox" id="landuse" />LANDUSE</span>     </span></a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" >
                        <img src="images/soil.jpg" alt="" />
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link" ><label><input type="checkbox" id="soil" />SOIL</label></span>       </span></a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/settlement.jpg" alt="" />
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">RIVER</span>     </span></a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/settlement.jpg" alt="" />
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">LITHOLOGY</span>     </span></a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/settlement.jpg" alt="" />
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">GWP</span>       </span></a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/settlement.jpg" alt="" />
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">CADASTRIAL</span>        </span></a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/settlement.jpg" alt="" />
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">GEOMORPHOLOGY</span>     </span></a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/settlement.jpg" alt="" />
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">SETTLEMNTS</span>        </span></a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="images/road.jpg" alt="" />
                        <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                        <span class="sdt_wrap">
                            <span class="sdt_link">ROADS</span>     </span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebutton">
            <div class="device__screen">
                <div id="menu-icon-wrapper" class="menu-icon-wrapper" style="visibility: hidden">
                    <svg width="1000px" height="1000px">
                        <path id="pathA" d="M 300 400 L 700 400 C 900 400 900 750 600 850 A 400 400 0 0 1 200 200 L 800 800"></path>
                        <path id="pathB" d="M 300 500 L 700 500"></path>
                        <path id="pathC" d="M 700 600 L 300 600 C 100 600 100 200 400 150 A 400 380 0 1 1 200 800 L 800 200"></path>
                    </svg>
                    <button id="menu-icon-trigger" class="menu-icon-trigger"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- menu-icon-wrapper -->
            <div id="dummy" class="dummy">
                <div class="dummy__item">
                    <select name="country_id" id="state_id" tabindex="1">
                        <option value="">-- Select state --</option>
                        <option value="India">-- India --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="dummy__item">
                    <select name="district_id" id="district_id" tabindex="2">
                        <option value="">-- Select district --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="dummy__item">
                    <select name="village_id" id="village_id" tabindex="3">
                        <option value="">-- Select village --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6"><nav class="cl-effect-20"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info show-popup"><span data-hover="QueryBuilder">QueryBuilder</span></a></nav>


        </div>

        </div>
         <!-- Element to pop up -->



    <div id="map" class="map">
        <div>
            <span class="reference">All Rights Reserved 
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>




    <script src="sideicon_file/js/main.js"></script>

    <script src="jsuntitled/ol.js"></script>
    <script>

var landuseLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
    coordinates: [-124.73142200000001, 24.955967,
                    -66.969849, 49.371735],
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states'},
     maxZoom: 19
    }),
    visible: false,
  });

  var  soilLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
  coordinates: [79.14511833527447, 20.987418098133496, 79.2018842619151, 21.050233196545],
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/sagy/wms',
          params: {'LAYERS': 'sagy:pachgaon_LULC'},
          maxZoom: 19
        }),
        visible: false
      });

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [landuseLayer, soilLayer],
  renderer: 'canvas',
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attributionOptions: ({
                    collapsible: false
                })
            }).extend([
                new ol.control.ZoomSlider(),
                new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({
                    extent: [
                        813079.7791264898, 5929220.284081122,
                        848966.9639063801, 5936863.986909639

                    ]
                }),

                new ol.control.Rotate(),
                new ol.control.OverviewMap(),
                new ol.control.ScaleLine(),
                new ol.control.FullScreen(),
                new ol.control.MousePosition({
                    coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
                    projection: 'EPSG:4326'
                })
            ]),

  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([
                new ol.interaction.Select({
                    condition: ol.events.condition.mouseMove
                })
            ]),


            view: new ol.View({
                center: new ol.geom.Point([-10997148, 4569099])
                    .transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:4326').getCoordinates(),
                zoom: 4
            }),

            target: 'map'
        });


$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  var layer = {

    landuse: landuseLayer,
    soil: soilLayer,


  }[$(this).attr('id')];
  layer.setVisible(!layer.getVisible());
});

        // define a custom control that can be used to draw points
      var DrawControl = function (opt_options) {
            var options = opt_options || {};
            this.active = options.active || false;
            var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                source: options.source,
                type: 'Point'
            });
            var this_ = this;
            var handleDrawPoint = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (!this.active) {
                    this_.getMap().addInteraction(draw);
                    this.active = true;
                } else {
                    this_.getMap().removeInteraction(draw);
                    this.active = false;
                }
            };

            // this will be the ui of the component
            var anchor = document.createElement('a');
            anchor.href = '#draw-point';
            anchor.innerHTML = 'New Point';

            // bind to click and touchevents to support mobile
            anchor.addEventListener('click', handleDrawPoint, false);
            anchor.addEventListener('touchstart', handleDrawPoint, false);

            var element = document.createElement('div');
            element.className = 'ol-control draw-point ol-unselectable';
            element.appendChild(anchor);

            ol.control.Control.call(this, {
                element: element,
                target: options.target
            });
        };
        // inherit base functionality from ol.control.Control
        ol.inherits(DrawControl, ol.control.Control);

        // init a vector layer whose source can be used with our new control
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource,
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#ffcc33',
                    width: 2
                }),
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 7,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#ffcc33'
                    })
                })
            })
        });

        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

        // here we use our new control
        map.addControl(new DrawControl({
            source: vectorSource
        })); 


    </script>





<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.ol-full-screen-false').click(function () {
                var isFullScreen = $("#hdnIsFullScreen").val();
                if (isFullScreen == "false") {
                    $('#map').css({ 'height': '100%', 'top': '0' });
                    $("#hdnIsFullScreen").val("true");
                }
                else if (isFullScreen == "true") {
                    $('#map').css({ 'height': '550px', 'top': '115px' });
                    $("#hdnIsFullScreen").val("false");
                }
            });


/**combobox code for state districtand village */
            $("#state_id").change(function () {
                $("#district_id").html("");
                $("#village_id").html("");
                $("#village_id").append("<option>-- Select village --</option>");
                var district = "";
                for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    district = district + "<option value='District" + i + "'>District" + i + "</option>";
                }
                $("#district_id").append("<option>-- Select district --</option>" + district);
            });

            $("#district_id").change(function () {
                $("#village_id").html("");
                var village = "";
                for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                    village = village + "<option value='Village" + i + "'>Village" + i + "</option>";
                }
                $("#village_id").append("<option>-- Select village --</option>" + village);
            });

            /**
            * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
            * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
            * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
            * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
            * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
            */
            $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter', function () {
                var $elem = $(this);
                $elem.find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                         'width': '110px',
                         'height': '60px',
                         'left': '0px'
                     }, 400, 'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({ 'top': '55px' }, 500, 'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({ 'height': '45px' }, 300, function () {
                         var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                         if ($sub_menu.length) {
                             var left = '50px';
                             if ($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index() + 1)
                                 left = '-50px';
                             $sub_menu.show().animate({ 'left': left }, 200);
                         }
                     });
            }).bind('mouseleave', function () {
                var $elem = $(this);
                var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                if ($sub_menu.length)
                    $sub_menu.hide().css('left', '0px');

                $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({ 'height': '0px' }, 300)
                     .andSelf().find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                         'width': '0px',
                         'height': '0px',
                         'left': '85px'
                     }, 400)
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({ 'top': '10px' }, 500);

            });
        });

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. This looks like there's conflict on the jQuery library and a best use case to use `$.noConflict()`. If you could post your full code, we will be able to help you out. `:)` Cheers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, by using  jQuery's noconflict mode. http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/

```
<!-- load jQuery 2.2.0 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var jQuery_2_2_0 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.12.0 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var jQuery_1_12_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

then use jQuery_2_2_0('#selector').function(); 
or 
jQuery_1_12_2('#selector').function();

rather than $('#selector').function(); or jQuery('#selector').function();

Answer (score 3):

Try this to use two jQuery versions.

```
<script src="jquery.latest-version.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.oldest-version.js"></script>

<script>
// Restore globally scoped jQuery variables to the first version loaded (the latest)
// and affect into `$old` the current (the oldest).
$old = $.noConflict();
console.log($); // This is the latest jQuery
console.log($old); // This is the oldest jQuery
</script>
```

This is how does it work into jQuery:

```
(function (factory) {
    // Save the jQuery var already existing...
    var initialClass = window.jQuery,
        // ...and affect our jQuery.
        api = window.jQuery = factory;
    api.noConflict = function () {
        // But if `noConflict` is used, jQuery is setted by initial existing jQuery saved...
        window.jQuery = initialClass;
        // ...and our own jQuery is returned.
        return api;
    };
}(function () {
    // Normal definition of jQuery class here.
}));
```

1. So, first load the latest.
2. Then load the oldest.
3. Use noConflict from oldest to restore latest into `$` and affect oldest into `$old`.

Comment: actually, you should put '$old = $.noConfiic' above the old one, just staying... your always going to get the "new" version.

Comment: so do i need to rename the jquery by old or new version or i have to use the old n new lib

Comment: First use the latest, after use the oldest.